# ACF select field within a repeater field that is in flexible content not showing

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an issue with the select field not showing.

I have flexible rows and then repeaters within that but the select/radio/checkbox dont show at all in the repeaters.

I have read through reams of related questions but not getting it to show.

I need this is the most basic terms like https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/

Where it just changes the value.

I have tried get sub and the sub and it is just blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "the select/radio/checkbox dont show at all in the repeaters" you mean on the backend or on the frontend?

Comment: on the front end and if it returns bool(false)

Comment: I just want to remind you that you will only get the value of your select/radio/checkbox to the frontend and not the UI. Can you show us your code so far.

Comment: All i really want is exactly this https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/ in a repeater field. it works outside of the loop but not in a repeater with neither get_sub_field nor the_sub_field.

<p>Color: <?php the_field('color'); ?></p>

Just not able to get it working in the repeater.

Comment: I could not imagine it without your code. Please update your question with your code in it so we can assess you properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="main-section" id="<?php the_sub_field('unique_id'); ?>" style="padding: <?php the_sub_field('section_padding'); ?>">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php while ( have_rows('content_blocks') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="block">
                <?php $value = get_sub_field('column_width'); var_dump($value); ?>
                <?php the_sub_field('block'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be the column_width sub field